# cron.daily seems to run but doesn't log any activity

Tags: 9.04, cron

We have a number of scripts setup to run in the `/etc/cron.daily directory` - some of them show evidence of being run at about the right time (files are archived/compressed and truncated), but others seem to be ignored.

Checking both `/var/log/cron.log` and `/var/log/syslog` lists none of the daily jobs - only the hourly (and a couple of 20 minute jobs).

Is there some other log somewhere? The crontab contains these lines:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 4    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Comment: Try to remove all dots in the script names

Answer (score 3):

What are the 20-minute jobs?  It looks like you pasted `/etc/crontab`, and it has no 20-minute entries.

What is the contents of `/var/log/cron.log`?

Do the permissions on `/etc/cron.daily` look right?  (e.g. should be at least `r-x` root)

Do the scripts inside `/etc/cron.daily` have execute permissions?

What does

```
run-parts --test --report /etc/cron.daily
```

print?

What happens if you add a new script in that directory that does something trivial that you can verify, e.g.

```
date >> /tmp/date.out
```

What does `/etc/syslog.conf` contain?  It should be something like:

```
cron.*                          -/var/log/cron.log
```

If it's `cron.notice` or `cron.warn` or `cron.err` rather than `cron.*`, then not all activity will be logged to `/var/log/cron.log`.

Answer (score 0):

If a cronjob has output or fails, cron will mail the user about it if the bsd-mailx package installed. Read such mails with the `mail` command.

Comment: You can install any mail server you like, not just bsd-mailx.  I am pretty sure that you can also edit a config file somewhere to use another mail server, but having one locally means mail won't be lost should the other server be down or unreachable temporarily.